# Problem in Latex2rtf

Tags: errors, conversion

I installed LaTeX2rtf 2.1.1 GUI from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/latex2rtf/files/latex2rtf-win/). I also installed MikTeX, Imagemagick and ghostscript, which is automatically detected in the environment tab. But when I run the program on a .tex file, it shows the following error.

> (Not set):1 only a single file can be
>   processed at a time.
>
> (Not set):1 Error! Type "latex2rtf -h"
>   for help
>
> Press any key to continue

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.